# application performance decrease a lot in docker

Tags: performance, docker

I'm using docker to run an molecular dynamics application Gromacs. I find a great application performance decrease in docker. I use the "top" command and find that there are about 40% CPU used by system 60% CPU used by user. While I running the application on native node without docker, 99% CPU are used by user. Will it be the reason that the application performance decrease?

Comment: Depends on whether the application is CPU bound or not. Are you running this natively on Linux or Mac/Windows?

Comment: @R0MANARMY  The application is CPU bound. we run the application in native linux. According to our instance, the speed is two to five times faster than that in docker. It seems that the application is load imbalance in docker. I don't know why

Comment: Did you try pinning the container to specific cores with: `docker run -it --rm --cpuset=0 <image> --cpu 1`? Might help if the application is cpu bound. Not sure about your workload but also make sure it does not share resources with other containers.

Comment: Another thing worth looking into, recent versions of Gromacs can offload some of the processing to the graphics card. That's something you can enable in when running in the container as well, but doesn't happen out of the box.

Comment: @abronan I'm sure there is no other containers. Every container run on a dedicate computer. I will try to pinning the container to specific core.

Comment: @R0MANARMY In fact, my computer don't have standalone graphic card. I I'm very curious about why the application running in docker cause extra system call?